# How to install package in EC2 ubuntu machine while bootstrapping CLI?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

How to install a package on an Ubuntu EC2 instance, during bootstrap through CLI. Is it possible by using Userdata?

Comment: Yes it is possible via Userdata.

Comment: ssh -i /tmp/xxxxx.pem -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ubuntu@${PUBLIC_IP} "sudo apt-get install python  -y"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user data is supported on Ubuntu.  He's an example of how using it might look when building out a new instance:

```
$ cat > init.sh
apt-get -y install mypackage
^D
$ aws ec2 run-instances \
    --iam-instance-profile Name=my-ec2-profile \
    --image-id ami-fa82739a \
    --count 1 \
    --instance-type t2.nano \
    --key-name my-ssh-key \
    --security-groups my-security-group \
    --user-data file://init.sh
```

After the instance is available, you can check the logs to ensure the package install worked properly:

```
$ ssh -i my-ssh-key.pem ubuntu@new-instance-name
$ cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
```